# how do i make this function work with my button

Tags: javascript

I am making a basic blackjack game but i am having some problems.I need help making my stand button perform the function called keepcards i am unsure why it is not working, when the stand button is pressed is does not make the decision if the players score is more, less ore equal to the computers score.

```js
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

function random() {
  return randomnumber;
}

var total = randomnumber;

function dealcard() {
  total += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  document.getElementById('playerscards').value = total;

  if (total > 21) {
    alert("You have gone bust click new game to play again!");
  }
}

function keepcards() {
  if (total > 21) {
    alert("You lose!");
  } else if (total > computerscards) {
    alert("You win!");
  } else if (total = computerscards) {
    alert("It is a draw!");
  } else if (total < computerscards) {
    alert("You lose!");
  } else {
    alert("You lose!");
  }

}
```

```html
<head>
  <h1><i>BLACKJACK</i></h1>
  <h4>
    Computers Cards: <input type="text" id="computerscards" value="18">
    <br>Player 1 cards: <input type="text" id="playerscards">
  </h4>
</head>

<input type="button" value="start" onclick="document.getElementById('playerscards').value = random()">

<input type="button" value="deal" onclick="dealcard()">

<input type="button" value="stand" onclick="keepcards">

<input type="button" value="new game" onclick="window.location.reload()">

<p>To start the game press start and draw a card<br> Press deal to add a new card <br> press stand if you do not wish to draw a new card<br> Prsee new game if you want to refresh the page to play a mew game</p>
```

Comment: Hi Owen, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you reduce your code down to a [mcve], please, rather than including _all_ of your code.

Comment: Have you **debugged** you code ever to see if function `random()` returns random number always or not?

Answer (score 0):

`else if (total = computerscards)` should be `else if (total == computerscards)`

You're currently assigning computerscards to total, not comparing them, and the result of that is always true, so you will never hit the next `else if`.

EDIT :

`onclick="keepcards"` should be `onclick="keepcards()"`

Also , `return randomnumber` will always return the *same* number, not re-generate one each time. Your function should `return  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)`.

Your `<head>` is inside the `<body>`.

The last comparison `else if (total < computerscards)` is useless, because it does the same thing as the final `else`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is his main problem. It is not clear, but he says : "it does not make the decision if the players score is more, less ore equal". As if no alert was shown

Comment: I know, actually this code is _so_ full of bugs. There are plenty of other answers, each one pointing at another bug...

Answer (score 0):

When providing functions as strings, you need to include the parentheses `()`. It should be `...onclick="keepcards()">`

Updated code below:

```js
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

function random() {
  return randomnumber;
}

var total = randomnumber;

function dealcard() {
  total += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  document.getElementById('playerscards').value = total;

  if (total > 21) {
    alert("You have gone bust click new game to play again!");
  }
}

function keepcards() {
  if (total > 21) {
    alert("You lose!");
  } else if (total > computerscards) {
    alert("You win!");
  } else if (total = computerscards) {
    alert("It is a draw!");
  } else if (total < computerscards) {
    alert("You lose!");
  } else {
    alert("You lose!");
  }

}
```

```html
<head>
  <h1><i>BLACKJACK</i></h1>
  <h4>
    Computers Cards: <input type="text" id="computerscards" value="18">
    <br>Player 1 cards: <input type="text" id="playerscards">
  </h4>
</head>

<input type="button" value="start" onclick="document.getElementById('playerscards').value = random()">

<input type="button" value="deal" onclick="dealcard()">

<input type="button" value="stand" onclick="keepcards()">

<input type="button" value="new game" onclick="window.location.reload()">

<p>To start the game press start and draw a card<br> Press deal to add a new card <br> press stand if you do not wish to draw a new card<br> Prsee new game if you want to refresh the page to play a mew game</p>
```

Comment: Thank you but now it always displays the promt as a loss no matter what the score

Comment: That was problem #1. You need to keep debugging. Use `alert()` popups (Or even better [`console.log`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)) on your variables, and find out why they aren't comparing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what's on the end of all the function calls in your `onclick` attributes. See something missing?

`ThisIsAFunction()` vs `ThisIsAVariable`

Answer (score 0):

You are not invoking your function at the `onclick` event, therefore it is never called. Try `<input type="button" value="stand" onclick="keepcards()">`

Comment: got the alert to work, but now no matter what the score is it always displays the result as a draw

Comment: I don't know if this will make it work, but your code has a typo, at  `else if (total = computerscards)` change it to  `else if (total == computerscards)`.
Otherwise you are assigning a value instead of comparing two values.

Comment: made the change to    else if (total == compuerscards)  but this now displays a loss every time

Comment: Making progress at least. Why do you have the last `else` statement? It doesn't seem to do anything since you have all options covered. Go ahead and remove it. Post results.

Comment: Done his and now the stand button does not work at all and no alert is show

Comment: Can you please add this line at the top of your `keepcards()` function, then press F12 to open console as you interact with the game: `console.log("Total:", total, "\n", "Computer Cards:", computerscards)`